# Bold text on checkbox check

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div with an h3 tag who's text I would like to bold when a checkbox is checked. I have seen solutions with labels but I don't believe it works in my case. Here's the code:

HTML:

```
<div class="imagecontainer">
  <div id="imagewrap" class="wrap">
    <img src="../images/travel.gif" id="img_prev" width="450" height="450" />
    <h3 class="desc">"Perfection is not attainable, but if we chase perfection we can catch excellence."</h3>
  </div>
</div>

<input id="boldCheckbox" type="checkbox" class="boldCheckbox"/>
<label id="label1">Bold</label>
```

To be clear, I would like the h3 text with `class="desc"` to be bold on check. Thanks!

Comment: Isn't headng text **bold** by default?

Comment: Whether or not it is is besides the point. The goal is to leave it up to users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're OK using jQuery... here's a quite simple example:

```js
$('#boldCheckbox').on('change', function() {
  $('#imagewrap h3').css({fontWeight: this.checked?'bold':'normal'});
});
```

```css
h3 { font-weight : normal}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="imagecontainer">
  <div id="imagewrap" class="wrap">
    <h3 class="desc">"Perfection is not attainable, but if we chase perfection we can catch excellence."</h3>
  </div>
</div>

<input id="boldCheckbox" type="checkbox" class="boldCheckbox" />
<label id="label1">Bold</label>
```

Logically, if your `h3` is already **bold** by default than simply inverse the logic:

```
this.checked? 'normal' : 'bold'
```

Answer (score 3):

You need a change handler for the input:

```
document.getElementById("boldCheckbox").onchange = function() {
    var h3 = document.getElementsByClassName("desc")[0];
    if (this.checked) {
        h3.style.fontWeight = "bold";
    } else {
        h3.style.fontWeight = "normal";
    }
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jvk3qpvp/1/

Answer (score 3):

```
var btnBold = document.getElementById("boldCheckbox"),
    title   = document.querySelector("#imagewrap h3");

btnBold.addEventListener("change", function(){
   title.style.fontWeight = this.checked ? "bold" : "normal";
});
```

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/supusu/3/edit?html,js,console,output)***

Comment: Works perfectly also, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript to look at the checkbox and if it's checked, make it bold (font weight 700) and not, don't make it bold. Keep in mind the below code will show the h3 bold on page load. I'm not sure how you want to handle that.

```
$('#boldCheckbox').on('change', function () {
    if ($('#boldCheckbox').is(":checked")) {
        $('h3').css('font-weight', '700');
    }
    else {
        $('h3').css('font-weight', '100');
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kuwu6kog/

Answer (score 1):

WORKING 100%

Use this code to make H3 BOLDER

HTML

```
<div class="imagecontainer">
          <div id="imagewrap" class="wrap">
              <img src="icons/frontstreet.png" id="img_prev" width="450" height="450" />
              <h3 class="desc">"Perfection is not attainable, but if we chase perfection we can catch excellence."</h3>
          </div>
      </div>

      <input id="boldCheckbox" onclick="makeH3Bold(this)" type="checkbox" class="boldCheckbox"/>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function makeH3Bold(o){
if(o.checked){
    $('.desc').css('textShadow','#000000 1px 0px 0px');
}
else{
    $('.desc').css('textShadow','#FFFFFF 0px 0px 0px');
}}
```

Comment: It's not good to use `inline` JS... Program logic and template should never intersect that way.

Comment: You are right my dear, we can add onclick listener on 'boldCheckbox' using jquery in $(document).ready or window.onload function

Answer (score 0):

You can add other class in your tag with bold style. Try this:

```
document.getElementById("boldCheckbox").onchange = function() {
    var imageWrap = document.getElementById("imagewrap");
    var h3 = imageWrap.getElementsByTagName("h3")[0];
    if (this.checked) {
        h3.className = "desc selectedH3";
    } else {
        h3.className = "desc";
    }
}
```

`selectedH3` could be like:

```
.selectedH3 {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

This add or remove the class `selectedH3` from your `h3` tag.

Comment: h3.className = ""; would **remove all styles** defined in `.desc` and that's not only a `normal` font weight but also font size, color... you name it. Also, if one day he decides to `<h3 class="align-right desc pumpIt">` than using `h3.className = "";` he could lose any other needed class styles.

Comment: Good point. Thx to comment. So... replacing "desc" class to other similar like "undesc"? what do you think?

Comment: I think that if OP needs  just to toggle `"bold" / "normal"` than `.style` is good enough. Otherwise you could suggest an example that uses this: (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) !

Comment: it's new for everyone since it's a new member of the JS family (IE sucks with support). Use with caution.